# How do I get permitAll in Spring Security to NOT throw AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException in @Controller object?

Tags: exception, authentication, controller, authorization, spring-security

I have a controller that has many actions and it specifies a default class-level @PreAuthorize annotation, but one of the actions I want to let anyone in (the "show" action).

```
@RequestMapping("/show/{pressReleaseId}")
@PreAuthorize("permitAll")
public ModelAndView show(@PathVariable long pressReleaseId) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView(view("show"));

    modelAndView.addObject("pressRelease",
        sysAdminService.findPressRelease(pressReleaseId));

    return modelAndView;
}
```

Unfortunately, Spring Security throws this exception:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.credentialsNotFound(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:321)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:195)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:64)
```

How can I get Spring Security to NOT throw this exception? I just want to let anyone in - non-authenticated users and authenticated users - Everyone.

My only solution is to put this method into another controller altogether with no @PreAuthorize at all... which will work, but that's stupid. I want to keep all my press release actions in the same controller.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal way to allow anyone to access a controller method is to *not* annotate it with any Spring Security annotations; ie no `@PreAuthorize` no `@Secured` etc.

You should be able to simply remove `@PreAuthorize` from the `show()` method, any leave the annotation on the other methods in that controller. The other methods will remain secured regardless of what you do with the `show()` method.

Comment: Well that really sucks because that means instead of specifying a class-level default I must specify X identical @PreAuthorize annotations and then make X tests for each of the controller actions to verify that I didn't forget to include it for all of the actions other than the show() action. This is just bad design on spring security's part. they should have a "doNothing" command to allow for class-level defaults to work properly :(

Comment: Given that the contents of the `@PreAuthorize` annotation is a Spring EL expression, could you just write an expression that always returns true? ie `@PreAuthorize("true")`? I haven't tried it, but it seems like a possible workaround...

Comment: It was worth a try ;) But nope, doesn't work. Oh well... I have so many controllers with split security concerns that I think this is so messy on spring security's part to force the developer to test each and every action separately and not use class-level defaults. I gotta tell them to fix this because this is awful for big apps.

Comment: Default behaviour changed with version 2 of the plugin. Now everything is secured by default!

Answer (score 11):

I guess you don't have anonymouse authentication filter enabled.

If you use namespace configuration and `auto-config = "true"`, it should be enabled by default. If you don't use auto-config, you can enable anonymous filter as `<security:anonymous />`.

Comment: This is the best answer - see details here http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/anonymous.html

Comment: Whats the java config for this?

Answer (score 3):

The default changed with a newer version (version 2) of the spring security plugin. That means all controllers are secured by default (you need to login to see them). Removing @Secured will not work at all, it will still stay secured. You can change this default behaviour, but to me the new default behaviour makes sense because it is much more secure. And security is very important.

I only use

```
@Secured(['permitAll'])
```

for my controller, but it should also work for a method.

Comment: This is not valid Java, try `@Secured("permitAll")`