# Prevent AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException while unit-testing

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-security

How to prevent Spring Security from throwing `AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException` in my unit tests? I'd like the user not to be authenticated, or to be authenticated anonymously.

I tried to do it like this:

```
    SecurityContext ctx = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
    SecurityContextHolder.setContext(ctx);
//  ctx.setAuthentication();
```

but I don't know where to get that anonymous authentication object from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code example is very unspecific. I assume that you are using a basic configuration taken from [Spring Security getting started page](http://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/#scratch)

To authenticate a user anonymously you will need to put an anonymous user into the security context:

```
SecurityContext ctx = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
SecurityContextHolder.setContext(ctx);
ctx.setAuthentication(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("anonymous", "", Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ANONYMOUS"))));
```

Otherwise you should remove all security mappings or annotations from your relevant urls. See:

[How do I get permitAll in Spring Security to NOT throw AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException in @Controller object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487249/how-do-i-get-permitall-in-spring-security-to-not-throw-authenticationcredentials)