# How to disable spring security for particular url

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using stateless spring security,but in case of signup i want to disable spring security.I disabled  using

```
antMatchers("/api/v1/signup").permitAll().
```

but it is not working,i am getting error below:

```
 message=An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext, type=org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException
```

I think this means spring security filters are working

My url's order always will be "/api/v1"

My spring config is

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

         http.
         csrf().disable().
         sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).
         and().
         authorizeRequests().
         antMatchers("/api/v1/signup").permitAll().
         anyRequest().authenticated().
         and().
         anonymous().disable();
        http.addFilterBefore(new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

My authentication filter is

```
@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = asHttp(request);
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = asHttp(response);

        String username = httpRequest.getHeader("X-Auth-Username");
        String password = httpRequest.getHeader("X-Auth-Password");
        String token = httpRequest.getHeader("X-Auth-Token");

        String resourcePath = new UrlPathHelper().getPathWithinApplication(httpRequest);

        try {

            if (postToAuthenticate(httpRequest, resourcePath)) {            
                processUsernamePasswordAuthentication(httpResponse, username, password);
                return;
            }

            if(token != null){
                processTokenAuthentication(token);
            }
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (InternalAuthenticationServiceException internalAuthenticationServiceException) {
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
            logger.error("Internal authentication service exception", internalAuthenticationServiceException);
            httpResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        } catch (AuthenticationException authenticationException) {
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
            httpResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, authenticationException.getMessage());
        } finally {
        }
    }

     private HttpServletRequest asHttp(ServletRequest request) {
            return (HttpServletRequest) request;
        }

        private HttpServletResponse asHttp(ServletResponse response) {
            return (HttpServletResponse) response;
        }

        private boolean postToAuthenticate(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, String resourcePath) {
            return Constant.AUTHENTICATE_URL.equalsIgnoreCase(resourcePath) && httpRequest.getMethod().equals("POST");
        }

        private void processUsernamePasswordAuthentication(HttpServletResponse httpResponse,String username, String password) throws IOException {
            Authentication resultOfAuthentication = tryToAuthenticateWithUsernameAndPassword(username, password);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(resultOfAuthentication);
            httpResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            httpResponse.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            httpResponse.addHeader("X-Auth-Token", resultOfAuthentication.getDetails().toString());
        }

        private Authentication tryToAuthenticateWithUsernameAndPassword(String username,String password) {
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken requestAuthentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
            return tryToAuthenticate(requestAuthentication);
        }

        private void processTokenAuthentication(String token) {
            Authentication resultOfAuthentication = tryToAuthenticateWithToken(token);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(resultOfAuthentication);
        }

        private Authentication tryToAuthenticateWithToken(String token) {
            PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken requestAuthentication = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(token, null);
            return tryToAuthenticate(requestAuthentication);
        }

        private Authentication tryToAuthenticate(Authentication requestAuthentication) {
            Authentication responseAuthentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(requestAuthentication);
            if (responseAuthentication == null || !responseAuthentication.isAuthenticated()) {
                throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException("Unable to authenticate Domain User for provided credentials");
            }
            logger.debug("User successfully authenticated");
            return responseAuthentication;
        }
```

My controller is

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    /**
     * to pass user info to service
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "api/v1/signup",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        userService.saveUser(user);
        return "User registerted successfully";
    }
}
```

I am totally new to spring,please help me how to do it ?

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487249/how-do-i-get-permitall-in-spring-security-to-not-throw-authenticationcredentials

Answer (score 216, accepted):

When using `permitAll` it means every authenticated user, however you disabled anonymous access so that won't work.

What you want is to ignore certain URLs for this override the `configure` method that takes `WebSecurity` object and `ignore` the pattern.

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/v1/signup");
}
```

And remove that line from the `HttpSecurity` part. This will tell Spring Security to ignore this URL and don't apply any filters to them.

Comment: @JacobZimmerman https://spring.io/blog/2013/07/03/spring-security-java-config-preview-web-security/ the configurer for web security class

Comment: Just would like to add you have to extend `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and `override` this `method` in it.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Even after adding `web.ignoring.antMatchers(..)` as described I'm getting this error: `org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext`

Comment: Then you haven't configured things right else it would work.

Comment: I added this but POSTing to the API via Postman still returns `Cannot POST /api/datapoints` everytime.. I also tried the other answeres without success. Are there any other settings you can/have to do in addition to this?

Comment: "In Spring Security 5.7.0-M2 we deprecated the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, as we encourage users to move towards a component-based security configuration."
https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter

Answer (score 31):

I have a better way:

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/api/v1/signup/**").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
```

Comment: @ViacheslavShalamov In your `WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`'s `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method. See https://www.baeldung.com/java-config-spring-security

Comment: this is most common in the internet, actually it is wrong practice. if you permit all, you mean it still need to authenticate but you finally permit it. so why should we do authentication (I mean authentication filters will be still triggered)  for a sign up access?

Comment: @Chao, what do you recommend?

Answer (score 15):

```
<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>
```

Or with Java configuration:

```
web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
```

Instead of the old:

```
 <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" filters="none"/>
```

for exp . disable security for a login page :

```
  <intercept-url pattern="/login*" filters="none" />
```

Answer (score 12):

This may be not the full answer to your question, however if you are looking for way to disable csrf protection you can do:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/web/admin/**").hasAnyRole(ADMIN.toString(), GUEST.toString())
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/web/login").permitAll()
                .and()
                .csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/contact-email")
                .and()
                .logout().logoutUrl("/web/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/web/").permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("admin").password("admin").roles(ADMIN.toString())
                .and()
                .withUser("guest").password("guest").roles(GUEST.toString());
    }

}
```

I have included full configuration but the key line is:

```
.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/contact-email")
```

Answer (score 8):

As @M.Deinum already wrote the answer.

I tried with api `/api/v1/signup`. it will bypass the filter/custom filter but an additional request invoked by the browser for `/favicon.ico`, so, I add this also in web.ignoring() and it works for me.

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/v1/signup", "/favicon.ico");
}
```

Maybe this is not required for the above question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ignore multiple API endpoints you can use as follow:

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests() 
            .antMatchers("/api/v1/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("api/v1/authenticate**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("**").permitAll()
            .and().exceptionHandling().and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

*I faced the same problem here's the solution:*(**Explained**)

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/form").hasRole("ADMIN")  // Specific api method request based on role.
            .antMatchers("/home","/basic").permitAll()  // permited urls to guest users(without login).
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()       // not specified form page to use default login page of spring security.
            .permitAll()
             .and()
        .logout().deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")  // delete memory of browser after logout.

        .and()
        .rememberMe().key("uniqueAndSecret"); // remember me check box enabled.

    http.csrf().disable();  **// ADD THIS CODE TO DISABLE CSRF IN PROJECT.**
}
```