# Spring security permit a url

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have implemented a Rest api using spring and used Spring security for securing the api, my security config code is :

```
http
     .authorizeRequests()
     .anyRequest().authenticated()
     .and()
     .requestCache()
     .requestCache(new NullRequestCache())
     .and()
     .httpBasic();
```

this code will authenticate all the urls but I want to permit a specific url for anonymous users to sign-up in my application so I did change the security config to below code :

```
http
     .authorizeRequests()
     .antMatchers("/signup").permitAll()
     .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
     .and()
     .requestCache()
     .requestCache(new NullRequestCache())
     .and()
     .httpBasic();
```

but I still needs to be authenticated to access the /signup request call.
How can I permit just some request calls in my api?

Comment: Follow this links should solve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30366405/how-to-disable-spring-security-for-particular-url

Comment: thank you this solve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should Override configure method with WebSecurity parameter and use the following code to ignore the /signup request.

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    super.configure(web);
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/signup");
}
```