# Unauthorized OPTIONS-request

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, cors

I try to access my Spring-Boot-application with Oauth2-Authentication with angular2. When i send a post-request to **"oauth/token"** with my basic authentication including username and password to get a token, which works fine in postman, i get an **401 Unauthorized**. I know that my browser sends a preflight-request with the OPTIONS-method, and i have implemented my **security-configuration** so that it should ignore and allow the options request, but it doesnt work.

Here is my **security-configuration:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class OAuth2SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
      .usersByUsernameQuery(
       "select username, password, 1 from users where username = ?") 
      .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
       "select u.username, r.name from users u, roles r, role_users ru "
       + "where u.username = ? and u.id =  ru.users_id  and ru.roles_id = r.id ");
       auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
       .withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN");
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .anonymous().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/oauth/token").permitAll();

    }
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/oauth/token");
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

Especially the last configure-method should allow me to access the api and get a token.

What could be the problem? Thanks for all help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30366405/how-to-disable-spring-security-for-particular-url try to remove 'anonymous().disable()'

Comment: sadly, it didn't work

Comment: thanks for your help. it works either way with or without anonymous().disable(). I just started the server of the project-copy. Everything works fine

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the problem....the problem was me.

There is nothing wrong on this code. i just started the wrong server (copy project). Everything works fine.