# Spring Web Security permit index page

Tags: java, spring-security

I want to allow anonymous access to my index page, which means the URL will be either `localhost:8080/MyProject/` or `localhost:8080/MyProject/index.xhtml`. I have read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30366405/how-to-disable-spring-security-for-particular-url) but the case is different with mine. I tried to configure it like this:<>

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/javax.faces.resource/**", "/", "/index.xhtml").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
```

With the statement above, the URL `localhost:8080/MyProject/index.xhtml` will allow anonymous access but `localhost:8080/MyProject/` will still denied the access. Help?

Comment: just guessing, did you try to add `""` also ?

Comment: @Newbie: Could you add Spring Security log with `DEBUG` level enabled to your question? It will show the reason for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`.antMatchers("/*").permitAll()` or `.antMatchers("/MyProject/*").permitAll()`