# How to disable CSRF check in Spring WebService / Spring WS Security application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, soap, spring-ws, ws-security

I have an application that uses Spring WS and Spring WS security for creating SOAP web services. I am getting the following exception.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><script type="text/javascript">(window.NREUM||(NREUM={})).loader_config={licenseKey:"d89ec68706",applicationID:"74176617"};window.NREUM||(NREUM={}),__nr_require=function(e,n,t){function r(t){if(!n[t]){var i=n[t]={exports:{}};e[t][0].call(i.exports,function(n){var i=e[t][1][n];return r(i||n)},i,i.exports)}return n[t].exports}if("function"==typeof __nr_require)return __nr_require;for(var i=0;i<t.length;i++)r(t[i]);return r}({1:[function(e,n,t){function r(){}function i(e,n,t){return function(){return o(e,[u.now()].concat(f(arguments)),n?null:this,t),n?void 0:this}}var o=e("handle"),a=e(4),f=e(5),c=e("ee").get("tracer"),u=e("loader"),s=NREUM;"undefined"==typeof window.newrelic&&(newrelic=s);var p=["setPageViewName","setCustomAttribute","setErrorHandler","finished","addToTrace","inlineHit","addRelease"],l="api-",d=l+"ixn-";a(p,function(e,n){s[n]=i(l+n,!0,"api")}),s.addPageAction=i(l+"addPageAction",!0),s.setCurrentRouteName=i(l+"routeName",!0),n.exports=newrelic,s.interaction=function(){return(new r).get()};var m=r.prototype={createTracer:function(e,n){var t={},r=this,i="function"==typeof n;return o(d+"tracer",[u.now(),e,t],r),function(){if(c.emit((i?"":"no-")+"fn-start",[u.now(),r,i],t),i)try{return n.apply(this,arguments)}catch(e){throw c.emit("fn-err",[arguments,this,e],t),e}finally{c.emit("fn-end",[u.now()],t)}}}};a("actionText,setName,setAttribute,save,ignore,onEnd,getContext,end,get".split(","),function(e,n){m[n]=i(d+n)}),newrelic.noticeError=function(e,n){"string"==typeof e&&(e=new Error(e)),o("err",[e,u.now(),!1,n])}},{}],2:[function(e,n,t){function r(e,n){var t=e.getEntries();t.forEach(function(e){"first-paint"===e.name?c("timing",["fp",Math.floor(e.startTime)]):"first-contentful-paint"===e.name&&c("timing",["fcp",Math.floor(e.startTime)])})}function i(e,n){var t=e.getEntries();t.length>0&&c("lcp",[t[t.length-1]])}function o(e){if(e instanceof s&&!l){var n,t=Math.round(e.timeStamp);n=t>1e12?Date.now()-t:u.now()-t,l=!0,c("timing",["fi",t,{type:e.type,fid:n}])}}if(!("init"in NREUM&&"page_view_timing"in NREUM.init&&"enabled"in NREUM.init.page_view_timing&&NREUM.init.page_view_timing.enabled===!1)){var a,f,c=e("handle"),u=e("loader"),s=NREUM.o.EV;if("PerformanceObserver"in window&&"function"==typeof window.PerformanceObserver){a=new PerformanceObserver(r),f=new PerformanceObserver(i);try{a.observe({entryTypes:["paint"]}),f.observe({entryTypes:["largest-contentful-paint"]})}catch(p){}}if("addEventListener"in document){var l=!1,d=["click","keydown","mousedown","pointerdown","touchstart"];d.forEach(function(e){document.addEventListener(e,o,!1)})}}},{}],3:[function(e,n,t){function r(e,n){if(!i)return!1;if(e!==i)return!1;if(!n)return!0;if(!o)return!1;for(var t=o.split("."),r=n.split("."),a=0;a<r.length;a++)if(r[a]!==t[a])return!1;return!0}var i=null,o=null,a=/Version\/(\S+)\s+Safari/;if(navigator.userAgent){var f=navigator.userAgent,c=f.match(a);c&&f.indexOf("Chrome")===-1&&f.indexOf("Chromium")===-1&&(i="Safari",o=c[1])}n.exports={agent:i,version:o,match:r}},{}],4:[function(e,n,t){function r(e,n){var t=[],r="",o=0;for(r in e)i.call(e,r)&&(t[o]=n(r,e[r]),o+=1);return t}var i=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;n.exports=r},{}],5:[function(e,n,t){function r(e,n,t){n||(n=0),"undefined"==typeof t&&(t=e?e.length:0);for(var r=-1,i=t-n||0,o=Array(i<0?0:i);++r<i;)o[r]=e[n+r];return o}n.exports=r},{}],6:[function(e,n,t){n.exports={exists:"undefined"!=typeof window.performance&&window.performance.timing&&"undefined"!=typeof window.performance.timing.navigationStart}},{}],ee:[function(e,n,t){function r(){}function i(e){function n(e){return e&&e instanceof r?e:e?c(e,f,o):o()}function t(t,r,i,o){if(!l.aborted||o){e&&e(t,r,i);for(var a=n(i),f=v(t),c=f.length,u=0;u<c;u++)f[u].apply(a,r);var p=s[y[t]];return p&&p.push([b,t,r,a]),a}}function d(e,n){h[e]=v(e).concat(n)}function m(e,n){var t=h[e];if(t)for(var r=0;r<t.length;r++)t[r]===n&&t.splice(r,1)}function v(e){return h[e]||[]}function g(e){return p[e]=p[e]||i(t)}function w(e,n){u(e,function(e,t){n=n||"feature",y[t]=n,n in s||(s[n]=[])})}var h={},y={},b={on:d,addEventListener:d,removeEventListener:m,emit:t,get:g,listeners:v,context:n,buffer:w,abort:a,aborted:!1};return b}function o(){return new r}function a(){(s.api||s.feature)&&(l.aborted=!0,s=l.backlog={})}var f="nr@context",c=e("gos"),u=e(4),s={},p={},l=n.exports=i();l.backlog=s},{}],gos:[function(e,n,t){function r(e,n,t){if(i.call(e,n))return e[n];var r=t();if(Object.defineProperty&&Object.keys)try{return Object.defineProperty(e,n,{value:r,writable:!0,enumerable:!1}),r}catch(o){}return e[n]=r,r}var i=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;n.exports=r},{}],handle:[function(e,n,t){function r(e,n,t,r){i.buffer([e],r),i.emit(e,n,t)}var i=e("ee").get("handle");n.exports=r,r.ee=i},{}],id:[function(e,n,t){function r(e){var n=typeof e;return!e||"object"!==n&&"function"!==n?-1:e===window?0:a(e,o,function(){return i++})}var i=1,o="nr@id",a=e("gos");n.exports=r},{}],loader:[function(e,n,t){function r(){if(!x++){var e=E.info=NREUM.info,n=d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];if(setTimeout(s.abort,3e4),!(e&&e.licenseKey&&e.applicationID&&n))return s.abort();u(y,function(n,t){e[n]||(e[n]=t)}),c("mark",["onload",a()+E.offset],null,"api");var t=d.createElement("script");t.src="https://"+e.agent,n.parentNode.insertBefore(t,n)}}function i(){"complete"===d.readyState&&o()}function o(){c("mark",["domContent",a()+E.offset],null,"api")}function a(){return O.exists&&performance.now?Math.round(performance.now()):(f=Math.max((new Date).getTime(),f))-E.offset}var f=(new Date).getTime(),c=e("handle"),u=e(4),s=e("ee"),p=e(3),l=window,d=l.document,m="addEventListener",v="attachEvent",g=l.XMLHttpRequest,w=g&&g.prototype;NREUM.o={ST:setTimeout,SI:l.setImmediate,CT:clearTimeout,XHR:g,REQ:l.Request,EV:l.Event,PR:l.Promise,MO:l.MutationObserver};var h=""+location,y={beacon:"bam.nr-data.net",errorBeacon:"bam.nr-data.net",agent:"js-agent.newrelic.com/nr-1167.min.js"},b=g&&w&&w[m]&&!/CriOS/.test(navigator.userAgent),E=n.exports={offset:f,now:a,origin:h,features:{},xhrWrappable:b,userAgent:p};e(1),e(2),d[m]?(d[m]("DOMContentLoaded",o,!1),l[m]("load",r,!1)):(d[v]("onreadystatechange",i),l[v]("onload",r)),c("mark",["firstbyte",f],null,"api");var x=0,O=e(6)},{}],"wrap-function":[function(e,n,t){function r(e){return!(e&&e instanceof Function&&e.apply&&!e[a])}var i=e("ee"),o=e(5),a="nr@original",f=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,c=!1;n.exports=function(e,n){function t(e,n,t,i){function nrWrapper(){var r,a,f,c;try{a=this,r=o(arguments),f="function"==typeof t?t(r,a):t||{}}catch(u){l([u,"",[r,a,i],f])}s(n+"start",[r,a,i],f);try{return c=e.apply(a,r)}catch(p){throw s(n+"err",[r,a,p],f),p}finally{s(n+"end",[r,a,c],f)}}return r(e)?e:(n||(n=""),nrWrapper[a]=e,p(e,nrWrapper),nrWrapper)}function u(e,n,i,o){i||(i="");var a,f,c,u="-"===i.charAt(0);for(c=0;c<n.length;c++)f=n[c],a=e[f],r(a)||(e[f]=t(a,u?f+i:i,o,f))}function s(t,r,i){if(!c||n){var o=c;c=!0;try{e.emit(t,r,i,n)}catch(a){l([a,t,r,i])}c=o}}function p(e,n){if(Object.defineProperty&&Object.keys)try{var t=Object.keys(e);return t.forEach(function(t){Object.defineProperty(n,t,{get:function(){return e[t]},set:function(n){return e[t]=n,n}})}),n}catch(r){l([r])}for(var i in e)f.call(e,i)&&(n[i]=e[i]);return n}function l(n){try{e.emit("internal-error",n)}catch(t){}}return e||(e=i),t.inPlace=u,t.flag=a,t}},{}]},{},["loader"]);</script><script type="text/javascript">window.NREUM||(NREUM={});NREUM.info={"beacon":"bam.nr-data.net","queueTime":0,"licenseKey":"d89ec68706","agent":"","transactionName":"MldVZUJYCkoDABVeWwsdcUReWhBQDQ1OU14EXFBeHlQNXQYPBEBVF1cZUkNLAgMhEBNRYgxXQHxZXQBVBxQARVFLQkVeU1wXSj0VCFJD","applicationID":"74176617","errorBeacon":"bam.nr-data.net","applicationTime":5}</script>
  <meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE">
  <title>403 Forbidden</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    html * { padding:0; margin:0; }
    body * { padding:10px 20px; }
    body * * { padding:0; }
    body { font:small sans-serif; background:#eee; }
    body>div { border-bottom:1px solid #ddd; }
    h1 { font-weight:normal; margin-bottom:.4em; }
    h1 span { font-size:60%; color:#666; font-weight:normal; }
    #info { background:#f6f6f6; }
    #info ul { margin: 0.5em 4em; }
    #info p, #summary p { padding-top:10px; }
    #summary { background: #ffc; }
    #explanation { background:#eee; border-bottom: 0px none; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="summary">
  <h1>Forbidden <span>(403)</span></h1>
  <p>CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.</p>


  <p>You are seeing this message because this site requires a CSRF cookie when submitting forms. This cookie is required for security reasons, to ensure that your browser is not being hijacked by third parties.</p>
  <p>If you have configured your browser to disable cookies, please re-enable them, at least for this site, or for &#39;same-origin&#39; requests.</p>

</div>

<div id="explanation">
  <p><small>More information is available with DEBUG=True.</small></p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm using spring ws-security to send plain text username-password for authorization.

How do I disable CSRF check in this application?

This is my **security-policy.xml**.

```xml
<xwss:SecurityConfiguration
    xmlns:xwss="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/xwss/config">
    <xwss:RequireUsernameToken
        passwordDigestRequired="false" nonceRequired="false" />
</xwss:SecurityConfiguration>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to look at [this](https://blog.netgloo.com/2014/09/28/spring-boot-enable-the-csrf-check-selectively-only-for-some-requests/), to do it I override the matches method, as described there, to avoid csrf for url containing specific pattern

Comment: @MatteoZanini thanks for the response. Please correct me if I'm wrong. I'm using spring- ws-security and not spring security. I have org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.WsConfigurerAdapter and org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. Or, can I uses both together to avoid CSRF error?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it, in **pre Spring Security 4**:

Custom **Request Matcher**:

```
@Component
public class CsrfSecurityRequestMatcher implements RequestMatcher {
    private RegexRequestMatcher protectedMatcher = new RegexRequestMatcher("(/path_with_csrf/.*)", null);

    @Override
    public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {          
        return protectedMatcher.matches(request);
    }
}
```

Security config:

```
 <security:csrf request-matcher-ref="csrfSecurityRequestMatcher" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Please correct me if I'm wrong. I'm using spring- ws-security and not spring security. I have org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.WsConfigurerAdapter and org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. Or, can I uses both together to avoid CSRF error?

Comment: Could you try like [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-csrf) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30366405/how-to-disable-spring-security-for-particular-url)

Comment: Hi @matteo. This is spring security. What I am using is, spring ws-security. It's for SOAP web services.

Comment: I also use that for soap web services, but I don't know if you can use both together, sorry