# How to implement the HTTPS request to a particular path/url?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I want to implement a TLS certificate requirement to a certain URL in my Spring Boot application. Only one route will require a  certificate, while others will have their own configuration later on.

For this purpose, I created the configuration below. It's authenticating the "/someRoute/**" path but it doesn't accept my certificate, so shortly it refuses everything.

```
        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            System.out.println("version" + SystemProperties.get("java.version"));
            http
                    .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                    .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                    .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.requestMatchers("/receivePDRDataFromIntegrationGAP2/**").authenticated())
                    .requiresChannel(channel -> channel
                            .requestMatchers("/receivePDRDataFromIntegrationGAP2/**")
                            .requiresSecure()
                    )

                    .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                            .anyRequest().permitAll()
                    );
            return http.build();
        }
```

Also, you can see my application.yaml showen below.

```
  ssl:
    key-store: gap2-certificate/keystore.jks
    key-store-password: changeit
    key-alias: localhost
    key-password: changeit
    enabled: true
    trust-store: gap2-certificate/truststore.jks
    trust-store-password: changeit
    client-auth: want
```

I tried to remove `.authorizeHttpRequests(auth-> auth.requestMatchers("/receivePDRDataFromIntegrationGAP2/**").authenticated())` part and change the `client-auth:` with `need`. This time URL that I want accepts my certificate, but also whole web site expects an SSL certificate.

With the original code, my spring-security logs:

```
2023-10-09 15:04:45,708 DEBUG [https-jsse-nio-8082-exec-8] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy: Securing POST /receivePDRDataFromIntegrationGAP2/createPDRData?patientFiscalCode=TEST1&doctorFiscalCode=TEST2
2023-10-09 15:04:45,722 DEBUG [https-jsse-nio-8082-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.c.ChannelProcessingFilter: Request: filter invocation [POST /receivePDRDataFromIntegrationGAP2/createPDRData?patientFiscalCode=TEST1&doctorFiscalCode=TEST2]; ConfigAttributes: [REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL]
2023-10-09 15:04:45,730 DEBUG [https-jsse-nio-8082-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter: Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-10-09 15:04:45,736 DEBUG [https-jsse-nio-8082-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint: Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
2023-10-09 15:04:45,740 DEBUG [https-jsse-nio-8082-exec-8] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy: Securing POST /error?patientFiscalCode=TEST1&doctorFiscalCode=TEST2
2023-10-09 15:04:45,746 DEBUG [https-jsse-nio-8082-exec-8] o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy: Secured POST /error?patientFiscalCode=TEST1&doctorFiscalCode=TEST2
2023-10-09 15:04:45,785 DEBUG [https-jsse-nio-8082-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter: Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
```

Error I'm getting(from the point of sender):

```
403 : "{"timestamp":"2023-10-09T13:04:52.401+00:00","status":403,"error":"Forbidden","path":"/api/receivePDRDataFromIntegrationGAP2/createPDRData"}"
```

Request that I'm sending. (I'm sending the request from another spring-boot application.)

```
// Send a POST request
response = restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, requestEntity, String.class);
```

My certificate configuration in the sender:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() throws KeyStoreException, IOException, CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyManagementException {
    KeyStore clientStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    clientStore.load(new FileInputStream("store/clientBob.p12"), "changeit".toCharArray());

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContextBuilder.create()
            .setProtocol("TLS")
            .loadKeyMaterial(clientStore, "changeit".toCharArray())
            .loadTrustMaterial(new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
            .build();

    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
    HttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder.create().setSSLSocketFactory(sslConnectionSocketFactory).build();
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(connectionManager).build();

        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);

    return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
}
```

My headers etc:

```
Request Line: POST https://localhost:8082/api/receivePDRDataFromIntegrationGAP2/createPDRData?patientFiscalCode=TEST1&doctorFiscalCode=TEST2
Request Headers:
Accept: [text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*]
Content-Type: [application/json]
Content-Length: [1167]
Request Body: {"id":null, some object....}
```

I saw similar [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30366405/how-to-disable-spring-security-for-particular-url) regarding to this, and I tried to implement the code above by reading the answers but theirs is an older version and I couldn't implement it.

Comment: Ok, you didn't configure `x509()`, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/x509.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved my issue like showen below. Basically i add the x509 configuration and removed the requiresChannel. I wanted to add the x509 before asking question but couldn't succeed it because of the syntax.

```
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                    .authorizeHttpRequests(auth-> auth
                                    .requestMatchers("/somePath/**")
                                    .authenticated().anyRequest().permitAll())
                    .x509(httpSecurityX509Configurer ->
                            httpSecurityX509Configurer.subjectPrincipalRegex("CN=(.*?)(?:,|$)"))
                    .userDetailsService(userDetailsService());

            return http.build();
        }

        @Bean
        UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
            return username -> {
                if (username == null || username.isEmpty()) {
                    throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
                }

                return new User(username, "", AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_SSL_USER"));
            };
        }
```